# Stored procedure runs code much slower than SSMS

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sqlperformance

I have a stored procedure which takes around 20s to run code. When I copy the code directly into SSMS, it runs in < 1s. Now the complexity is that my code actually runs 20 other stored procedures - the main stored procedure does not do much at all other than call the other stored procedures.

I have read up on parameter sniffing, and have changed my code to deal with this, no impact. I have also tried the 'with recompile' hint both on calling the main stored procedure and also on the call to all the other stored procedures, and this made it slower.

What else could it be?

So my calling stored procedure looks like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spr_DoPersonMatch]
    @inPmq_ID bigint                    -- Passed in pending match ID
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    declare @pmq_ID bigint  
    set @pmq_ID = @inPmq_ID
    declare @Total_match_count as int = 0
    declare @match_rule as int
    declare @AuditMatch as bit = 0

    -- Match Rule 1 - FORENAME & SURNAME & NINO & either (NHSNO or UPN)
    exec dbo.spr_DoPersonMatchRule1 @pmq_ID,@AuditMatch ,@match_count = @Total_match_count output  
    if @Total_match_count > 0 set @match_rule = 1

    -- Match Rule 2 - FORENAME & SURNAME & NINO & either (NHSNO or UPN)
    if @Total_match_count < 1 -- If we have a match, do not do any more matches.  Drop through
    BEGIN
        exec dbo.spr_DoPersonMatchRule2 @pmq_ID,@AuditMatch ,@match_count = @Total_match_count output 
        if @Total_match_count > 0 set @match_rule = 2
    END
```

As I say, IF I copy the master stored procedure code above into SSMS and run it (setting the `inPmq_ID` at the top of the code) it runs in no time at all.

Anything I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are actually executing the SPROC in SSMS ? I have seen a mistake made where the programmer forgets they are actually executing the CREATE PROCEDURE script and not the underlying stored procedure. Reading your post it says "if I copy the ... code into SSMS" - if you literally did that, your query would build the proc, but would not execute it.

Comment: No, I am executing the code - its not just a CTRL+A, CTRL+V here, its the code after the "AS BEGIN" in the SPROC.  Also, the individual SPROCS have audit writes in the them, and the audit logs are being updated, so I 100% know that the child sprocs are being called.

Comment: Do you get the same output ? I'm guessing you do, but its worth asking.